# What does blank braces indicate in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What does `{}`   indicate in javascript?
For example

```
 var txt={};
```

`{}` means what?

Comment: not to confuse with `if(x) {}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means an empty object. `txt` is declared as a new object in javascript with no properties. If you wanted to add properties you could use this:

```
var txt = { prop1: 'value 1', prop2: 'value 2' };
```

and then you can retrieve the values using `txt.prop1` and `txt.prop2`.

Answer (score 6):

`{}` means that a variable is initialized with an empty object

so you may create some inner properties with `txt.property = ...` or also  `txt["property"] = ...`

or define inner objects too, with `txt.anotherobject = {}`

Answer (score 5):

It is equal to

```
var txt = new Object();
```

It create a new empty object with no properties